# What exactly is electrical energy (is it kinetic or potential energy)?

Tags: electrostatics, energy, potential-energy

I have a doubt  most sources like study.com wiki ... define electrical energy either as potential or as kinetic in the meantime i encountered this article http://amasci.com/miscon/ener1.html which speaks differently.

so I'm interested in what is right.

Comment: What is heat energy?  Kinetic or potential?  That is a similar qn

Comment: Energy associated with electric forces would be called electrical energy.

Answer (score 1):

You can explain Electrostatic potential energy in terms of both kinetic energy and potential energy.
In terms of potential energy : If we consider a system of particles, because there are mutual forces between them, we need to put in work to either assemble or disassemble the system. If we had a system of like charges, there would be mutual repulsion between them and thus we would need to do external work in order to assemble the system of charges. Here, by assembling I mean, taking the charges from infinity where they are complete out of each other's fields and bringing them to the desired locations. In case of unlike charges, the mutual Electrostatic forces of attraction would cause the particles to assemble on their own and as a result of this, we would need external work to disassemble the system of charges. Since we define the potential energy of a conservative force field as the negative of the work done, we have associated Electrostatic potential energy with the work needed to assemble or disassemble the system.
In terms of Kinetic Energy : If I consider the same system of like charges in their configuration, each charge is acted upon by repulsive forces due to other charges. So if we released the system, according to Newton's Second Law, the charges will tend to be accelerated and by the time they are completely out of each other's influence, i.e at infinite separation, they would have acquired some kinetic energy. Provided no external forces act on the system, conservation of energy tells us that Change in potential energy = Change in kinetic energy and thus we can associate Electrostatic potential energy the kinetic energy of the charges of the system. a similar justification can be given for a system of unlike charges.
Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking of the electrostatic energy of a finite electric charge density distribution or of a collection of point charges in space, the electrostatic energy is potential energy.

If you consider propagating electromagnetic waves, the energy can be viewed as kinetic energy transported by the photons in the direction of wave propagation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, Kinetic energy. One must ask about the transferability of the energy. Kinetic energy can be transferred between objects. Potential energy cannot be transferred between objects. The equation for Kinetic energy is 0.5 mv^2, where m = mass and v = speed where as the equation for potential energy is mgh, where m = mass, g = gravity and h = height.